# Error when adding ofxPd to existing openframeworks android project: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: android, c++, xcode, openframeworks

I've have built an android application with OF and I want to add functionalities from ofxPd. The application works until I add ofxPd.

I have added the ofxPd folder to the addons folder of my project and also the path to the header search paths. I have also added the other C flags (-DPD -DHAVE_UNISTD_H -DUSEAPI_DUMMY).

However, I cannot make it work, I get this error and I do not know how to solve?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ofApp::audioReceived(float*, int, int)", referenced from:
      vtable for ofApp in ofApp.o
  "ofApp::audioRequested(float*, int, int)", referenced from:
      vtable for ofApp in ofApp.o
  "non-virtual thunk to ofApp::audioRequested(float*, int, int)", referenced from:
      vtable for ofApp in ofApp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong or what can I do to solve it?

If, as suggested in [here](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/xcode-4-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386/6957/10), I create a new project, I add the same addons, and I replace the code in the files `main.cpp`, `ofApp.cpp` and `ofApp.h`, I get the error: `"ofxSpatialHash.h" file not found`

Answer (score 0):

**Q**:

- Can you run one of the ofxPD examples without problems?

**Some initial stuff you could try** :

- I see you might be missing a needed flag: DHAVE_ALLOCA_H
- Are you sure "audioReceived" is defined in the ofApp.cpp file?

In my experience "non-virtual thunk…" means in general that there is a virtual member function defined that is not implemented… (hence the vtable error).

**References**

https://github.com/danomatika/ofxPd